# Is it possible to configure PHP linter to ignore some directories in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My whole question is in the title, I am wondering if it is possible to configure PHP linter to ignore some directories in Visual Studio Code.

It is linting all my vendors, and it complains on some things I don't care about. I want to ignore my `vendor` directory, so it stops putting some noise in the linters panel.

Comment: I have the same issue, the PHP linter is presently a cycle-waster and not usable on real-world projects. If there is a setting to operate only on open files, as [this issue claims](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/35089), I'd love to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can do that with the following command:

```sh
$ ./vendor/bin/phplint ./ --exclude=vendor
```

Here is a nice article with more information: https://bestofphp.com/repo/overtrue-phplint-php-http